# find elem in a list with datatype class

Tags: c++

I have trouble to find a elem in a list

i read the documentation for the find function and its all good for datatypes like "int, string, etc. " but when im using a class as:

```
list<Person> mylist
```

i got some issues.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    int kontostand;
    string email;
    int alter;

    Person(int kontostand_, string email_, int alter_)
    {
        kontostand = kontostand_;
        email = email_;
        alter = alter_;
    }
};

int main()
{

    list<Person> myPerson;

    Person Kunde(2, "test", 1);
    Person Kunde2(3, "test2", 2);
    myPerson.push_back(Kunde);
    myPerson.push_back(Kunde2);

    list<Person>::iterator x;

        //troouble at this line
    x = find(myPerson.begin(), myPerson.end(), Kunde);


    return 0;
}
```

the result is: "no match for 'operator=='(operand types are 'Person' and 'const Person')

how to find the Element in a List ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't define an `==` for you. You need to tell it how to compare two `Person` objects for equivalence. The most straightforward way is to provide `operator==`

```
class Person {
public:
    int kontostand;
    string email;
    int alter;

    Person(int kontostand_, string email_, int alter_)
    {
        kontostand = kontostand_;
        email = email_;
        alter = alter_;
    }
    bool operator==(const Person& other) const
    {
        return other.kontostand == kontostand &&
                other.email == email &&
                other.alter == alter;
    }
};
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yeYjt1Jix7YpZlFn)

The other option is to use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and provide your own comparator:

```
 auto x = std::find_if(myPerson.begin(), myPerson.end(), [&Kunde](const Person& other){
    return other.kontostand == Kunde.kontostand &&
    other.email == Kunde.email &&
    other.alter == Kunde.alter;});
```

#### [Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VBR2iomROLKMRsxK)

Comment: do you know where it is actually specified that `T` must have a `operator==`? I was looking for it on [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) but other than in the possible implementation i didnt find where it is explicitly mentioned

Comment: maybe it is isimply implied by "find searches for an element equal to value"

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: It's under [alg.find]: "Returns: The first iterator i in the range [first, last) for which the following corresponding
conditions hold: *i == value, pred(*i) != false [...] Returns last if no such iterator is found." [link to standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.find#1.1)

Comment: thank you. Usually cppref is rather accurate, so i guess "equal to value" is meant to be read as `*i == value`.

Comment: So, to summarize. `T` doesn't necessarily need to have an `operator==`, but an `operator==` that compares the two types must be found by ADL. Which means we could define a free-standing `operator==` for two Person objects

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I usually keep the latest draft of the standard around for reference when I want to see the "real" rules (language-lawyer type stuff)

Comment: thanks again, yes probably I should consult the standard more often, cppreference is awesome because it is written in simpler terms buts thats also a limitation

Answer (score 1):

`find` tries to compare elements in the list (how else could it tell if `Kunde` is in the lsit?) by using `==`. There is no `operator==` for `Person`, you need to define it. Something along the line of

```
class Person {
public:
    int kontostand;
    string email;
    int alter;

    Person(int kontostand, string email, int alter) : 
        kontostand(kontostand),
        email(email),
        alter(alter)
    {}
    bool operator==(const Person& other) const {
        return (kontostand == other.kontostand) 
            && (email == other.email)
            && (alter == other.alter);
    }
};
```

Better use the initializer list for the constructor. In your code the memebrs are first default initialized and then you assign the values. With the initializer list the members are only initialized.